# Why can't I sign into google map when being away from my apartment and using mobile data?

Tags: google-maps

My phone is Kyrocera Hydro Icon, with Android 4.4.2. I am in US and using Sprint network.

When I am in my apartment, google map will automatically log into my google account, no matter whether my phone is using mobile service or wifi.

When I am away from my apartment and my phone is using mobile data service, google map app will say that something link "can't sign in using my google account". The result of that is I can't retrieve the history of places which I have looked up, and I can't access the places which I have saved.

Why is the problem, and how can I solve it?

Thanks.

Comment: At least tell us the country & carrier name that you are using. Metro region or state/province may be helpful as well.

Comment: Is mobile data working at all? Can you visit websites that offer HTTPS? Sounds like a networking issue.

Comment: @G mobile data is working. I can visit https websites. Can it be a problem of account management by Android?